# Add systemd-analyze to yocto build

Tags: yocto

I'm building a yocto image for a raspberry pi model 3 and in order to analyze and later optimize the boot process I'd like to add the systemd-analyze package.

So I added

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " systemd-analyze"
```

to my `local.conf` but when I build the image bitbake yells at me

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'systemd-analyze' (but /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
```

Do I have to add an additional layer to use `systemd-analyze`?

```
  /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta \
  /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta-poky \
  /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/mtech/Workspace/rpi-yocto/poky-dunfell/meta-raspberrypi \
```

Comment: I added it to `IMAGE_INSTAL` and it worked. Just insure `systemd-analyze` is added to `FILES:${PN}-analyze`: `FILES:${PN}-analyze = "${bindir}/systemd-analyze"` in recipe systemd